# Unable to click Anchor link due to it's 'invisibiliy'

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an  element enclosed in a `div` tag. Following is the HTML:

```
<div id="btnCreditCard" class="paymentBtn creditcard" style="display: block;">
    <a class="button button-primary button-override has-icon-right" href="javascript:Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(1);">
        <i class="button-icon-left"></i>Continue To Order Review<i class="button-icon-right fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have tried every possible thing I knew even jQuery injection and clicking but still no vail. Code I tried so far:

```
#m = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnCreditCard > a')
                        #m = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]/a/i[1]')
                        #x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]/a')
                        #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver : x).click()

#driver.execute_script('( $("#btnCreditCard").hide() );')
                        #driver.execute_script('( $("#btnCreditCard").show() );')
                        #driver.execute_script('eval($("#btnCreditCard > a").attr("href")) ;')
                        #driver.execute_script('eval("Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(1)") ;')
                        #driver.execute_script('$("#btnCreditCard > a")[0].click();')
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Exception Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace: 
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///var/folders/4B/4Bd6e77uH-uNGxBS-xhds++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp13jGXK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8936:5)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///var/folders/4B/4Bd6e77uH-uNGxBS-xhds++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp13jGXK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11595:1)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/4B/4Bd6e77uH-uNGxBS-xhds++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp13jGXK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11612:11)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/4B/4Bd6e77uH-uNGxBS-xhds++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp13jGXK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11617:7)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/4B/4Bd6e77uH-uNGxBS-xhds++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp13jGXK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11559:5) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xx/Leo/xx/xxx", line 122, in addOrderFull
    m = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]').click()
```

I am using Python2.7

Comment: If the element is not visible, you can not click on it....not a surprise. Is it in some sort of menu that is hidden?

Comment: @epascarello but I am using FireFox as a driver and it's appearing visible to me.

Comment: @GabrielePrestifilippo you changed the entire thing, even HTML.

Comment: Is it a timing issue. Did you try to use the `wait.until` code and have it check the visibility?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, even set the time to 25 to 30 seconds still no vail. The code I gave do have `wait.until` call.

Comment: Can u try to use absolute xpath to find the element 'a' and click on it? (Just to see if it is the object identification issue). Are you sure that you do not have any other elements with the same id?  What is the exception? Please share that too of possible.

Comment: @VinothS I did try it: `x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]/a')`  I have run code again and share message shortly

Comment: @VinothS Question updated with Stacktrace.

Comment: @epascarello Question updated.

Comment: @Volatil3, x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]/a')  It is not absolute path. I mean from '/html/body.../a'  - My doubt is - you have another element matching this '//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]/a'  which is not visible. That is why you get the error.

Comment: @VinothS How do I get Abs XPath in Chrome?

Comment: I had tried to get it in firefox before. It worked. If you know HTML, just search it in the HTML source code. If there is more than one element with the id - 'btnCreditCard' - then this is the issue.

Comment: Ok I installed a plugin and it gave following: `/html[@class=' mac mozilla safari']/body[@class='NEGlobal HomePage2011 price2012']/div[@id='container']/div[@id='bodyArea']/div[@class='newegg-global']/div[@class='bodyArea']/div[@class='aside']/div[@class='grpAction orderSummary']/div[@class='additional-info-groupbox']/div[@class='additional-info-button']/div[@class='call-to-action call-to-action-checkout']/div[@id='btnCreditCard']/a[@class='button button-primary button-override has-icon-right']`

Comment: Ok. even Abs xPath not solving issue. Same error

Comment: Is this possible for you to share the HTML sourcecode of the page?

Comment: @VinothS check this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jct30lqweuihdb4/source%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: @VinothS Any luck brother?

Comment: @Volatil3, I already checked the files you had uploaded. I just wanted the HTML file in which you have the element to be clicked. If you have the page in chrome, just right click->view page source-> search for 'btnCreditCard' . Does it find only one? I am saying this because i had a similar issue that i have 2 elements with the same id - one is visible to me - other element was hidden. webdriver was trying to click on the hidden element.

Comment: Also, check if it helps. 


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="javascript:Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(1);"]').click()

Comment: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file`